# How to correctly implement cross browser compatible nextSibling/nextElementSibling function without JQuery?

Tags: javascript, cross-browser

I need to update some old Javascript to be cross browser compatible. The code was originally created for IE6 and uses nextSibling and previousSibling a lot due to the way the HTML is laid out.

Obviously nextSibling and previousSibling don't work the same way in Firefox, etc. The next best choice, nextElementSibling, doesn't work in older IE browsers. It seems that what I need to do is create a **nextElementSibling** equivalent function that works in the majority of browsers.

Here is my attempt that doesn't seem to work quite right:

```
function getNextElementSibling(CurrentElement) {
    if (CurrentElement.nextElementSibling) {
        return CurrentElement.nextElementSibling
    } else {
        do {
            CurrentElement = CurrentElement.nextSibling;
        } while (CurrentElement && CurrentElement.nodeType !== 1);
        return CurrentElement;
    }
}
```

What needs to be done to fix/replace it?

Please note that JQuery and other libraries are **not an option**.

Comment: You should name the function correctly. It returns the nextElement, not the next sibling. Also, constructor functions should be the only variables named uppercase.

Comment: Why does your attempt not seem to work quite right? It looks good to me.

Comment: 1. It's meant to return the next sibling as per 'nextSibling' not the next element.
2. I haven't tracked down why yet (the real code is huge as is the document it's working against) but the code above still doesn't produce the same result in both Ff and IE (it's hiding/showing sections)

Comment: So why do you use nextElementSibling if you want the text nodes, too?

Comment: I've clarified the question by rewording the two instances where I used nextSibling when I implied nextElementSibling. What I want is a function that duplicates nextElementSibling (i.e. ignores text nodes) and works in both Firefox, Safari and IE6, 7, 8, & 9. My previous comment didn't say that I meant nextSibling in the way that IE does nextSibling - basically the same as nextElementSibling

Comment: OK, thanks for the clarification. Could you please elaborate about why you think the function fails, including some DOM and (un-)expected test results? The "hiding/showing sections does not work" does not seem related.

Answer (score 1):

I have the same issue and i find it strange that dojo-framework (which I'm using v1.7) doesn't provide a convenience method for this.

My browser compatibility issue is related to IE versions 7,8 and 9, and webkit browsers (recent versions), i've also tested it on Firefox 14 and seems to work.

```
function getNextElementSibling(element) {

    if (element.nextElementSibling) {

        return element.nextElementSibling;
    } else {

        return element.nextSibling;
    } 
}
```

Comment: Beware, nextSibling is not a drop in replacement for nextElementSibling. The nextSibling property will return all siblings (comments as well as text will be considered siblings) therefore you will need to add conditions to filter unneeded types out or else you will end up with strange bugs in he event that your else condition is used on a legacy browser.